# Binding Container and binding context in a ADF application

Tags: oracle-adf

Can someone please explain the concept of a `binding container` and `binding context` concepts in ADF ? How the above objects are instantiated during an  ADF page lifecycle ? Does a `binding container` contain an instance of `binding context` or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takle a look at these recorded trainings, they may help.
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/insiderBinding1/BindingsPart1.html

Answer (score 2):

**Binding Context** is basically a map between data controls and page definition (contain bindings information) of pages in the application. Whenever an adf client or controller initiates an interaction with the business service, it(the interaction) is managed by the application through a single object. This object is the Binding Context.

**Binding Container** is used to instantiate page bindings. it contains bindings , executables and datacontrol mappings.

**Binding Context contains Binding Container**

**Simple Example to clarify it further**.. :

BindingContext bindingctx=BindingContext.getCurrent(); //get bindingcontext

BindingContainer binding=bindingctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();//get container

DCBindingContainer bindingsImpl = (DCBindingContainer) binding; // get the Application Module(Data Control) using the references in Container.

DCIteratorBinding dciter = bindingsImpl.findIteratorBinding(“**iterName**”);  // find the iterator using the Data Control

ViewObject vo=dciter.getViewObject();// get View Object instance for the VO whose iterator is "dciter"

Answer (score 0):

In Brief, Data Bindings file contains the page Map, Page Definition references , References to Data Controls.

Data Controls file contains the data control definitions